# using the function findMovie for the second time, visual studio throws exception

Tags: c, function, struct

visual studio throws an exception to the second instance of find movie under case c, it says it has not been initialized yet although in the local windows it shows the struct with info inside?Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'tempMovie' is being used without being initialized. this only happens the second time i try to use the struct tempMovie

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CONST 100
typedef struct movies {
    char title[30];
    char UPC[12];
    int qnty;
    double price;
}movies;
void sortMovies(struct movies main[], int nOfMovies);
void changeMovie(struct movies main);
int findMovie(struct movies main, int nOfMovies, struct movies tempMovie);
struct movies newMovie();


int main()
{
    int nOfMovies = 0, findR, stop = 0, nOfMoviesArr[CONST];
    char decider;
    while (stop != 1)
    {
        movies main[CONST];
        movies tempMovie;
        printf("(A)dd a new movie\n(C)hange a Movie's Information \n(D)elete a Movie \n(L)ist All Movies\n(Q)uit\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &decider);

        switch (decider)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            tempMovie = newMovie();
            findR = findMovie(main[nOfMovies], nOfMovies, tempMovie);
            if (findR == -1)
            {
                nOfMovies += findR;
                break;
            }
            else
            main[nOfMovies] = tempMovie;
            nOfMovies++;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            findR = findMovie(main[nOfMovies], nOfMovies, tempMovie);
            changeMovie(main[findR]);
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':

            break;
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            sortMovies(main, nOfMovies);
            break;
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("An invalid option was selected!");
        }
    }


}

struct movies newMovie() {
    movies new;

    printf("enter movie upc:");
    scanf("%s", &new.UPC);
    printf("enter movie title:");
    scanf("%s", &new.title);
    printf("enter movie qauntity:");
    scanf("%d", &new.qnty);
    if (new.qnty <= 0)
    {
        printf("quanitity must be greater than 0");
        printf("enter movie qauntity:");
        scanf("%d", &new.qnty);
    }

    printf("enter movie price:");
    scanf("%lf", &new.price);
    if (new.price <= 0)
    {
        printf("price must be greater than 0");
        printf("enter movie price:");
        scanf("%lf", &new.price);
    }
    return new;
}


int findMovie(struct movies main, int nOfMovies, struct movies tempMovie)
{

    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < nOfMovies; count++)
    {
        if (tempMovie.UPC != main.UPC)
        {
            return count;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error");
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
void changeMovie(struct movies main)
{
    char decider;

    printf("would you like to change the value? y or no input");
    switch (decider)
    {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        printf("enter movie title:");
        scanf("%c", main.title);
        printf("enter movie qauntity:");
        scanf("%d", main.qnty);
        if (main.qnty <= 0)
        {
            printf("quanitity must be greater than 0");
            printf("enter movie qauntity:");
            scanf("%d", main.qnty);
        }

        printf("enter movie price:");
        scanf("%lf", main.price);
        if (main.price <= 0)
        {
            printf("price must be greater than 0");
            printf("enter movie price:");
            scanf("%lf", main.price);
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("An invalid option was selected!");



    }

}
void sortMovies(struct movies main[], int nOfMovies)
{
    int i, sflag, count = 0;
    char* temp;

    do
    {
        sflag = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < nOfMovies; i++)
        {
            if (main[i - 1].title > main[i].title)
            {
                temp = main[i - 1].title;
                strcpy(main[i - 1].title, main[i].title);
                strcpy(main[i].title, temp);
                sflag = 1;
            }
        }
        count++;
    } while (sflag);

    for (i = 0; i < nOfMovies; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%.2lf\n", main[i].title, main[i].UPC, main[i].qnty, main[i].price);
    }


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Error may be due to any or many the following reasons:

1. In changeMovie(), the variable decider is not scanned.
2. In scanf(),  use a spaces omitted before `"%c"` and `"%s"` (Use `" %c"` and `" %s"`)
3. In changeMovie(), syntax error while scanning (Use `&main.qnty` instead of `main.qnty`)
4. The function changeMovie() is changing the formal parameters and not altering the actual parameters

Also, there are a few logical errors. For instance, in the line `if (new.price <= 0)` a `while` should be used instead of an `if`